# Setting delimiter in the QgsAggregateCalculator

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, vector-layer, aggregate, delimiter

With PyQGIS I want to aggregate some fields in my layer.
When I use:

```py
mylayer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.StringConcatenate, myField)
```

Then I get a concatenated string without a delimiter. So I tried to add one but failed.

```py
mylayer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.StringConcatenate, myField, delimiter=',')
```

> QgsVectorLayerr.aggregate():'delimiter' is not a valid keyword argument

```py
mylayer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.StringConcatenate, myField,
                  QgsAggregateCalculator.AggregateParameters(delimiter=','))
```

> 'delimiter' is an unknown keyword argument

```py
mylayer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.StringConcatenate, myField, 
                  QgsAggregateCalculator.AggregateParameters(delimiter(',')))
```

> name 'delimiter' not defined

```py
mylayer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.StringConcatenate, myField,
                  QgsAggregateCalculator.AggregateParameters.delimiter(','))
```

> 'AggregateParameters' object attribute 'delimiter' is an instance attribute

```py
mylayer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.StringConcatenate, myField,
                  QgsAggregateCalculator.AggregateParameters.setDelimiter(','))
```

> AttributeError: type object 'AggregateParameters' has no attribute 'setDelimiter'

```py
mylayer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.StringConcatenate, myField,
                  QgsAggregateCalculator.delimiter(','))
```

> TypeError: QgsAggregateCalculator.delimiter(): first argument of
> unbound method must have type 'QgsAggregateCalculator'

The help, that shows up when I type the expression, says:

> aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.Aggregate, QString, QgsAggregateCalculator.AggregateParameters parameters=QgsAggregateCalculator.AggregateParameters(), QgsExpressionContext context=None)

It looks like, if you don't provide parameters, it would use the standard parameters. So I tried `QgsAggregateCalculator(mylayer).setDelimiter(',')`, but that doesn't make any difference. The concatenated string still doesn't contain a delimiter.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`QgsAggregateCalculator`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAggregateCalculator.html) like this:

```py
params = QgsAggregateCalculator.AggregateParameters()
params.delimiter = ","

aggr = mylayer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.StringConcatenate, myField, params)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. I think, i wouldn't have found this solution in years.