# Creating list from field values with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, pyqgis-3, list

How is it possible to create a list from the values of a single field in a shp using PyQGIS?

Example:

| field_capital_name |
| --- |
| London |
| Paris |
| Rome |

```py
list1 = [London, Paris, Rome]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using [`QgsVectorLayerUtils`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayerUtils.html#module-QgsVectorLayerUtils)

> Contains utility methods for working with [`QgsVectorLayers`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=qgsvectorlayers#module-QgsVectorLayer).

This approach is available since QGIS 3.

Let's assume there is a layer called *'test'* with several features in it, see image below. In my example, I will refer to the field `"test"`.

[image: input]

With the following script it is possible *to create a list from the values of a single field*:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
list_of_values = QgsVectorLayerUtils.getValues(layer, 'test')[0]

print(list_of_values)
```

which will result in this:

```
['Lorem ipsum 1', 'Lorem ipsum 2', 'Lorem ipsum 1']
```

To get only unique values, apply the following:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
list_of_values = QgsVectorLayerUtils.getValues(layer, 'test')[0]

list_of_values = list(set(list_of_values))

print(list_of_values)
```

which will result in this:

```
['Lorem ipsum 1', 'Lorem ipsum 2']
```

Keep in mind that list sorting is not covered in this answer.

Comment: All the answers work well so far. By the way, when dealing with a field with unique values (such as "id"), ascending sorting is already performed using the second example.

Comment: Otherwise, to get values sorted it is possible to add 'list_of_values.sort()' before the 'print'.

Answer (score 9):

A solution based on the usage of [`QgsAggregateCalculator`](https://qgis.org/api/3.16/classQgsAggregateCalculator.html#a51eb9f5752cf107d72266829a21cf2fa) with `ArrayAggregate` and `StringConcatenateUnique` parameters.

> Available aggregates to calculate.
>
> Not all aggregates are available for all field types.

This approach is available since QGIS 2.16.

Let's assume there is a layer called *'test'* with several features in it, see the image below. In my example, I will refer to the field `"test"`.

[image: input]

With the following script it is possible *to create a list from the values of a single field*:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
list_of_values = layer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.ArrayAggregate, "test")[0]

print(list_of_values)
```

which will result in this:

```
['Lorem ipsum 1', 'Lorem ipsum 2', 'Lorem ipsum 1']
```

To get only unique values, apply the following:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

params = QgsAggregateCalculator.AggregateParameters()
params.delimiter = ","

list_of_values = layer.aggregate(QgsAggregateCalculator.StringConcatenateUnique, "test", params)[0].split(",")

print(list_of_values)
```

which will result in this:

```
['Lorem ipsum 1', 'Lorem ipsum 2']
```

Keep in mind that list sorting is not covered in this answer.

---

**References:**

- [Setting delimiter/filter in the aggregate function from QgsVectorLayer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423669/set-a-delimiter-filter-in-the-aggregate-function-from-qgsvectorlayer)

Answer (score 5):

Use getFeatures:

```
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ok_an_riks')[0]
list1 = [f['lansnamn'] for f in lyr.getFeatures()]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```py
# reference to the layer
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

# get its fields
fields = lyr.fields()

# get the index of the field
idx = fields.indexFromName('my_field_name')

# get unique values
uniq_vals = lyr.uniqueValues(idx)

# get all values
all_vals = []
for f in lyr.getFeatures():
    all_vals.append(f[idx])

    # or skip getting the index
    # all_vals.append(f['my_field_name'])
```